# How do i turn off individual lights using falloff in animation nodes?

Tags: animation, animation-nodes

I want to turn off a bunch of lights inside a collection using falloff in animation nodes but i cant find a node that connects the value of the light intensity to the falloff or a node that allows me to apply the falloff to all lights in the collection.

Thanks in advance for the help! :)

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to know how to access and modify each light's energy. Then evaluate the falloff in a subprogram and tweak each light's energy.

In order to know the property's name, you have to activate "Python tooltips" in the preferences :

[image]

Then hover you cursor over the field :

[image]

So, given the point light, you access its energy with an attribute node and the path `data.energy`. Similarly, if you want to access the color, you would use `data.color`.

[image]

For ease of use put all your lights in their own collection.

[image]

Add your falloff object (I chose a cube), tweak the fallof type and connect it to your subprogram.

[image]

Result :

[image]

Comment: Just like last time you come here and save my day! Thank you! <3

Comment: Always a pleasure to answer clear and precise questions :)

Answer (score 1):

We can also do this directly without using loop:

[image]